# How to convert Time (object) to datetime or timestamp data type in python?

Tags: python, pandas, time, timestamp, python-datetime

Trying to convert object type variable to datetime type
`pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])`

```
0      13:08:00
1      10:29:00
2      13:23:00
3      20:33:00
4      10:37:00
```

> Error :<class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Please help how can I convert object to datetime and merge with date variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('datetime64')
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Not working. Time (object) does not have dates, it only contains hour,min,seconds.

Comment: this only works if existing data type is string (object).

Answer (score 0):

What you have are `datetime.time` objects, as the error tells you. You can use their string representation and parse to pandas datetime or timedelta, depending on your needs. Here's three options for example,

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [datetime.time(13,8), datetime.time(10,29), datetime.time(13,23)]})

# 1)
# use string representation and parse to datetime:
pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].astype(str))
# 0   2022-01-19 13:08:00
# 1   2022-01-19 10:29:00
# 2   2022-01-19 13:23:00
# Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

# 2)
# add as timedelta to a certain date:
pd.Timestamp('2020-1-1') + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))
# 0   2020-01-01 13:08:00
# 1   2020-01-01 10:29:00
# 2   2020-01-01 13:23:00
# Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

# 3)
# add the cumulated sum of the timedelta to a starting date:
pd.Timestamp('2020-1-1') + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str)).cumsum()
# 0   2020-01-01 13:08:00
# 1   2020-01-01 23:37:00
# 2   2020-01-02 13:00:00
# Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```